# Is there any plugin that record last opened image in eye of gnome in ubuntu? I want eye of gnome open last opened file when run

Tags: gnome, files

As the title state, is there anyway/any plugin in eye of gnome, that open last opened file? Because I use workspace restore after login/start up, and the restored eye of gnome is blank...

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Any help is appreciated. Thank you